# Put a prefix for ObjectID for MongoDB _id field

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to put a prefix before the auto generated `_id`, to identify from which collection came an id, but I still want to use the mongo unique id generator.

So I can know that this id `model_5e1a51821c9d44000089e3e0` came from the Model collection.

Is there a solution for that without messing with random string ?

**Edit**

The `_id` need to be string castable, since I use it as `id` in a graphQL object. I need to differentiate **ids** because I use an union in my schema and resolver need to know in which table to find the data.

Comment: _id by default is `ObjectId` and it's not random string, but `4-byte timestamp value + 5-byte random value + 3-byte incrementing counter`. So, you cannot use `Model_+random string` for ObjectId. You can generate Model_ + UUID() manually and set to `_id` before insert.

Comment: thanks Valijon I'm gonna do like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `_id` can be generated within an application with the constructor `ObjectId()`. If you want to add a prefix for the generated field, you can use an embedded document as a field for the `_id`, like this:

```
_id: {
    idPrefix: "Model",
    _id: ObjectId("5e1bd112b7f18a490a4bafb5")
}
```

Other way of identifying if a document is from another collection is use a separate `boolean` field:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("5e1bd112b7f18a490a4bafb5"),
  isFromModel: <boolean true or false>,
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but the problem is that I use graphql and I get the _id from an union (who contains 3 types `[User, Model, Network]`) and for the resolver I need to check from which table the id I get is from.
And I think your solution cannot provide a String **_id**, so I can't pass the _id in a graphql object

Comment: In such a case you can use two string fields: `<string from ObjectId>` and a second field called as `type`. Type has any of the values "User", "Model" or "Network". Your application can generate the `_id` with `ObjectId()` constructor and use the `str` property to get the string version of it (for example, `ObjectId().str` returns `"5e1c2bf8b7f18a490a4bafbb"`) . Use them as two string fields _or_ concatenate them (as `type + ObjectId string`) to have a single `_id` field  (e.g., `"User5e1c2bf8b7f18a490a4bafbb"`).

Comment: The [ObjectId constructor, methods and properties](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/index.html).

Comment: Yess so obvious ... I have just to put some prefix before the graphQL id and just split it before query the DB in the resolver ..... No need to change the mongo `_id` Thanks @prasad_

Answer (score 0):

There are some options available to do this, I'm just trying to tell you the way how would I do if I need this.

Step 1: You can generate the document and it will return you ObjectId (_id) .

Step 2: Take that value and prefix it with model like this.

`let _id=5e1a51821c9d44000089e3e0;let new_idValue="model_"+_id;`

Step3: Now update your document by _id and push new value in place of if as

`this.db.document.findByIdAndUpdate(_id,{$set:{{_id:new_idValue}})`

**This is what you can do. If you find some best solution than mine, let me know as well. I will highly appreciate.**

Comment: You cannot change `_id` once it's inserted

Comment: Ah! I am not referring to changing the key _id, I am referring to change its value.

Comment: Another option may be to get the value of _id and store it another field as a unique id.